# VXML on SpeechServer

Tags: xml, speech, vxml, voicexml

I have a question, at http://www.vxml.org/frame.jsp?page=t_1.htm
it says that i have to save a voicexmlfile as .xml

but when i create an new application on speech Server 2007, it says, that I can put there .speax files only ...

but when I do so, it doesn't work ...

Do I have to save it as a .speax?
Do I something wrong by creatng a new application on the server?

thanks :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
it doesn't matter 
i can save it as .speax, or .xml. or .vxml , ....
for the server it doesn't matter